# Is there any way i can change browse a file button to it's file path?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

i'm making a program which is need to browse a photo 
and i've put browse a file button and everything is working well, but i want 
when the user choose a file 
to change the button name to that file's path
please help.

i've tried to use global inside the function so i can name a variable out the function " browse a file " and inside the function change it's name and insert it inside the button but it didn't work with me, maybe i didn't know how or it doesn't work this way

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
def filename1():
window.filename1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",title="Select file", filetypes=(
    ('jpeg', "*.jpeg"), ("jpg", "*.jpg"), ("all files", "*.*")))
print(window.filename1) # here it's print the file path

filebrowsebutton1 = Button(text="Browse a file",command=filename1).place(x=60, y=280)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First returning the filename from `filename1()` will not change the text of the browse button.  Second `filebrowsebutton1` will not assigned the instance reference of `Button`, but `None` because you have chained the function `.place(...)`.

Below is an updated version of the code to solve the above issues:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')

def filename1():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/', title='Select file', filetypes=(('jpeg', '*.jpeg *.jpg'),('all files', '*.*')))
    if filename:
        # update button text with the selected filename
        browsebutton['text'] = filename

browsebutton = tk.Button(text='Browse a file', command=filename1)
browsebutton.place(x=60, y=200)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: what does browsebutton['text'] mean? i mean why did you put ['text'] ?

Comment: and how can i change the button's color?

Comment: `browsebutton['text'] = ...` means setting the `text` property of `browsebutton`.  You can use `browsebutton.config(text=...)` as well.  You can use similar statement to set the color of button, e.g. `browsebutton['bg'] = 'red'`.